# TailwindCss - Row becomes a column on mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design, tailwind-css, responsive, responsiveness

i would like to get some help with tailwindcss.
I have a layout where the column on desktop becomes a row on mobile.
This is the result on desktop

[image]

My code

```
 <div className='p-8'>
         <div className="grid grid-cols-4 font-bold">
             <p></p>
             <p>Price</p>
             <p>Size</p>
             <p>Color</p>
         </div>
         <div className="grid grid-cols-4">
             <p className="font-bold">Name</p>
             <p>Text</p>
             <p>Text</p>
             <p>Text</p>
         </div>
         <div className="grid grid-cols-4">
             <p className="font-bold">Brand</p>
             <p>Text</p>
             <p>Text</p>
             <p>Text</p>
         </div>
     </div>
```

Everything looks fine so far.

On mobile the layout should look like this

[image]

As you can see the row with Price Size and Color becomes a column.
Does anyone could help me to understand how to solve this problem with tailwindcss.

Thank you very much

Have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example that sets the grid to place items by column when lower than the default `sm` (640px) breakpoint of Tailwind.

[More about responsive setting in Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design)

Hope it gets close to the desired result.

The example runs in the snippets below for convenience. To see it adjust to screen sizes, use the full page option.

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="p-8 grid grid-flow-col sm:grid-flow-row">
    <div className="grid grid-row-4 auto-rows-fr sm:grid-cols-4 font-bold">
      <p></p>
      <p>Price</p>
      <p>Size</p>
      <p>Color</p>
    </div>
    <div className="grid grid-row-4 sm:grid-cols-4">
      <p className="font-bold">Name</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div className="grid grid-row-4 sm:grid-cols-4">
      <p className="font-bold">Brand</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```